# How to say “vollschwitzen” (German) in English?

Tags: word-request, verbs, translation

It was just necessary to explain to somebody in English why I am not wearing the team shirt of my national team although they play this evening. I don’t want to wear it right now, because the weather is quite hot outside. If I did, it would be full of sweat this evening and smelling. I will put it on later.

Is there a single verb in English which could be used in this context? In German I could just say:

> Ich will das Trikot nicht vollschwitzen.

and *vollschwitzen* means to make some clothes full of sweat over time, which implies it will smell bad. Is there a similar verb in English, so that I could just say something like:

> I don’t want to ... my team shirt.

Maybe a colloquial one? If there isn’t, how could I say this more elegant / in a shorter way?

Comment: *Trikot* here would probably be expressed by most sports fans as *(team) jersey*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In American English we would say

> I don't want to **get** my team shirt **sweaty**.

No native speaker would use *to soil* in this context. *To soil* means 'to make dirty'. In relation to clothes, it has the specific meaning of 'to soil one's clothes by defecating (or: pooping) in them'. Thus, the farther away from *soil* you stay, the better.

According to Google translate, English *to soil* translates as *beschmutzen, 
verschmutzen, verunreinigen, besudeln.* If any of those fit, feel free to use it. However, if they don't fit, it's because we wouldn't use *to soil* in his context. Ever. Not in contemporary, everyday English. Likewise, we wouldn't say *to pollute* or *to foul* either.

*To get something sweaty* is what you want to say.

Therefore I have given you the same phrase as an earlier answer, but some other information about *to soil*.

Comment: I agree with everything here. Just wanted to add that we might use _dirty_ in place of _sweaty_. When I'm out jogging or playing football, _dirty_ implies _sweaty_. _Dirty_ doesn't necessarily mean _dirt-covered_, particularly when talking about laundry. For example, I could point to a laundry basket, and ask: _Are these clothes dirty or clean?_

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you could use the verb *soil*:

> I don't want to soil my team shirt

but I don't think any native speaker would use that in the context of making something *sweaty*. It is used more to imply the application of dirt or, heaven forfend, faeces.

Colloquially, I would say

> I don't want to get my team shirt sweaty